# How do I authenticate with microsoft and retrieve game achievements?

Tags: xbox, xbox-one, xbox-live

My goal is to retrieve all achievements data for an xbox game without using third party APIs.

I have registered an app here: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

I am using Postman to test the REST capabilities of the xbox live api but I believe the documentation is incorrect regarding authentication. Using the client_credentials workflow and my registered app credentials I have retrieved a "very large" bearer token using this url https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token.

I am querying the xbox live api using the following url: https://achievements.xboxlive.com/users/xuid(MY_XUID)/achievements but it is returning...

```
{
    "code": 23,
    "source": "Progress",
    "description": "No valid claims were found on the request.",
    "traceInformation": "007:d126836c-833b-4ee2-afe3-cd05b22d1f45"
}
```

It seems like there is no reference to such an error in any google search or in any documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have been attempting to get "Login via Microsoft Account" flow working for my app, specifically for the Xbox Creators Program and various xbox live endpoints. But I have not been able to solve how to get the actual Xbox Live auth token for the user. The UHS and TOKEN that makes the "XBL 3.0" authorization header.

Comment: i get "Xuid could not be parsed from request url"

Answer (score 1):

Did you create your app directly via apps.dev.microsoft.com or via the Windows Store developer portal?

One reason you may not be able to access it, is you haven't run the initial test which spins up the app.

Best way to get running is to:
1: go to dev.windows.com
2: register an app for the store
3: go to the Services -> live section
4: enable you app for Xbox Live Creators
5: Complete the registration
6: Go to the Settings and hit "Test"
7: play with your access using your secret keys.

Hope this helps.